# I lent him money two years ago

Tags: grammar

Do the four sentences have the same meaning?

> I last lent him money two years ago.

> I lent him money for the last time two years ago.

> That was the last time I lent him money two years ago.

> That was the last time I was going to lend him money two years ago.

Answer (score 2):

> I last lent him money two years ago.

The most recent time I lent him money was two years ago. (I haven't lent him any money since then.)

> I lent him money for the last time two years ago.

I lent him money two years ago. Then maybe he vanished or died. Or perhaps I decided not to do it again.

> That was the last time I lent him money two years ago.

Gibberish!

> That was the last time I was going to lend him money two years ago.

Gibberish!

Comment: Thank you. How can I express *I decided not to do it again after that time; it is the last time forever*?

Comment: @Steven. I don't think you've upvoted **any** comments or answers yet. We don't **have** to help you, you know :-)

Comment: Sorry for it. I've now upvoted it.

Comment: "I last lent him money two years ago and I decided never to do so again." But you don't have to say everything in a single sentence! It may sometimes be more natural to break it in half. "I last answered one of his questions a  few minutes ago. It was a thankless task and I resolved never to do it again!"

Comment: OK, I see. Thank you very much.